# Magento admin product image create new blank image

Tags: php, magento-1.7

When i upload product images from admin site, it create new empty image record in addition to the product image. Again i need to remove the empty record. pls help?

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of your module has observer with SaveProductTabData() or other method , and calls for save() method inside, as a result product is saved twice, and durning second saving creates entry with same name + '_1' postfix (for instance your_image_name_1.jpg). Just delete model save() method.